# How to use UART interrupts for PIC24 with MCC?

Tags: microcontroller, c, uart, microchip, mplabx

I'm using UART6 to interrupt my program whenever it receives an incoming string. I'm using the MCC to generate functions that I can use but I'm not sure how to call my interrupt function. Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    //Initialize the device
    SYSTEM_Initialize();
    LED4_SetLow();               //3V3 LED on during operation    
    Power_LED1_SetHigh();        //Green LED on
    Power_LED2_SetLow();         //Red LED off 
    UART6_SetRxInterruptHandler(*controls);

    while(1)
    {   
        sensor_data();
    }
    return (0);
}
```

How do I enter my function `controls` once a string has been received?

Comment: The handler will be called for every character, you need to put them in a buffer and check for a full string then do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when the interrupts are configured properly the interrupt for your UART needs to be enabled in some register bit(s). Before enabling there is also a need to setup the pointer (address) of the interrupt handler routine. In the simplest case for some MCUs the handler address gets placed into the interrupt vector table which is typically in a dedicated memory location. In more complex cases the MCU has a more generic interrupt vector for some group of interrupt sources. The specific handler addresses for the group of interrupt sources are placed into a table. Later a software routine that responds to the actual group interrupt then figures out what specific source triggered the interrupt and calls the appropriate handler via the correct table entry.

Note that the more complex case I described is really just an adaptation of the simpler case. It is the MCU hardware that takes care of responding to the enabled interrupt source. It correlates the source to a specific interrupt vector table entry and then gets the handler address from the vector and calls to the handler routine.